# MySQL login works for me but not my friend using VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a program that takes info from the user and logs them into a database using Phpmyadmin, our code is the exact same, except for my friend he can't login.

Code is here:

Both our database name, tables and columns are the EXACT same, he can register the account to the DB so it stores it, but when he tries to login with the same information it says that it was unsuccessful.

## SignUpForm(THIS WORKS)

```
Public Class frmSignup
Dim ServerString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;Database=accountinfo"
Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
            MsgBox("Successfully connected to DB")

        Else
            SQLConnection.Close()
            MsgBox("Failed to connect to DB")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub SaveAccountInformation(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    SQLConnection.Close()
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
    If txtPasswd.Text = txtPasswd2.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords Match!")

        Dim HashedPass As String = ""

        'Converts the Password into bytes, computes the hash of those bytes, and then converts them into a Base64 string

        Using MD5hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()

            HashedPass = System.Convert.ToBase64String(MD5hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPasswd.Text)))

        End Using


        Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO accountinfodb(`Usernames`, `Passwords`) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "','" & HashedPass & "')"
        SaveAccountInformation(SQLStatement)



        MessageBox.Show("Account Successfully Registered")
        frmLogin.Show()
        frmLoginScreen.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords Do Not Match!")
        txtPasswd.Text = Focus()
        txtPasswd.Clear()
        txtPasswd2.Text = Focus()
        txtPasswd2.Clear()

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

## LOGIN FORM(THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR HIM BUT IT WORKS FOR ME)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class frmLogin

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim conStr = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;Database=accountinfo"
    Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM accountinfodb WHERE Usernames = @uname AND `Passwords` = @pword"

    Dim HashedPass As String = ""

    'Converts the Password into bytes, computes the hash of those bytes, and then converts them into a Base64 string

    Using MD5hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()

        HashedPass = System.Convert.ToBase64String(MD5hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPasswd.Text)))

    End Using

    ' this object will be closed and dispose @ End Using
   Using dbCon As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
        ' the command object likewise
       Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbCon)

            dbCon.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@uname", txtUsername.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@pword", HashedPass))

            ' create a Using scope block for the reader
           Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                If rdr.HasRows Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " & txtUsername.Text)
                    frmProduct.Show()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Oops! Login unsuccessful!(Password/Username may be wrong, or the user may not exist!")
                    txtUsername.Clear()
                    txtUsername.Focus()
                    txtPasswd.Clear()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using           ' close/dispose command

    End Using               ' close/dispose connection


End Sub
End Class
```

## WOULD ALSO LIKE TO MENTION

I shared my files over google drive with him, so he did not copy and paste any of the code. This is the exact same files from MY computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue, he was using an outdated version of MySQL while my version was the most up to date. I reinstalled the proper MySQL server to the newest version and it worked!